# How to get notified of modification in the memory in Linux

Tags: linux, memory

In a userspace program in Linux, I get a piece of memory via allocation from the heap, then the pointer is distributed to a lot of other components running in other threads to use. I would like to get notified when the said piece of memory is modified. I can of course develop a custom userspace solution for other components to use when they try to modify the memory. The problem in my case is that these are legacy components and they can write to memory in many occasions. So I'm wondering whether there is a similar API like inotify (get notified when file is changed) or other approaches in order to get notified when a piece of memory is changed.

I considered using mmap and inotify, which obviously won't work if the changes are not flushed. Any suggestions are appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4):

You **CAN** add an [**inotify watch**](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) which will trigger on [**msync()**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/msync) on the mmap-ed file.

This requires patching the Linux Kernel to [**enable support for a new inotify watch**](https://gist.github.com/TheCodeArtist/5874669). The patch adds a new flag **IN_SYNC** - a new inotify event that is triggered whenever msync() is carried out on the mmap-ed file.

Patch has been tested on v2.6.37 of the Linux Kernel.

```
From 83edf446e92c86c738337ca4a35eab48e2f4e0eb Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Chinmay V S <cvs268@gmail.com>
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 13:53:57 +0800
Subject: [PATCH] Add mmap-ed file support to inotify

This patch adds a new flag IN_SYNC. This is a new inotify event that is
triggered whenever msync() is carried out on a mmap-ed file.

Signed-off-by: Chinmay V S <cvs268@gmail.com>
---
 fs/sync.c                             |  5 +++++
 include/linux/fsnotify.h              | 16 ++++++++++++++++
 include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h      |  1 +
 include/linux/inotify.h               |  3 ++-
 mm/msync.c                            |  4 ++++
 5 files changed, 28 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

diff --git a/fs/sync.c b/fs/sync.c
index ba76b96..174c2af 100644
--- a/fs/sync.c
+++ b/fs/sync.c
@@ -16,6 +16,7 @@
 #include <linux/buffer_head.h>
 #include <linux/backing-dev.h>
 #include "internal.h"
+#include <linux/fsnotify.h>

 #define VALID_FLAGS (SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WAIT_BEFORE|SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE| \
            SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WAIT_AFTER)
@@ -190,6 +191,10 @@ static int do_fsync(unsigned int fd, int datasync)
        ret = vfs_fsync(file, datasync);
        fput(file);
    }
+
+   if (!ret)
+       fsnotify_sync(file->f_path.dentry);
+
    return ret;
 }

diff --git a/include/linux/fsnotify.h b/include/linux/fsnotify.h
index b10bcde..ef211fb 100644
--- a/include/linux/fsnotify.h
+++ b/include/linux/fsnotify.h
@@ -224,6 +224,22 @@ static inline void fsnotify_modify(struct file *file)
 }

 /*
+ * fsnotify_sync - file was synced
+ */
+static inline void fsnotify_sync(struct dentry *dentry)
+{
+   struct inode *inode = dentry->d_inode;
+   u32 mask = FS_SYNC;
+
+   if (S_ISDIR(inode->i_mode))
+       mask |= FS_ISDIR;
+
+   fsnotify_parent(NULL, dentry, mask);
+   fsnotify(inode, mask, inode, FSNOTIFY_EVENT_INODE, NULL, 0);
+
+}
+
+/*
  * fsnotify_open - file was opened
  */
 static inline void fsnotify_open(struct file *file)
diff --git a/include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h b/include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h
index 7380763..35b5cb8 100644
--- a/include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h
+++ b/include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h
@@ -36,6 +36,7 @@
 #define FS_DELETE      0x00000200  /* Subfile was deleted */
 #define FS_DELETE_SELF     0x00000400  /* Self was deleted */
 #define FS_MOVE_SELF       0x00000800  /* Self was moved */
+#define FS_SYNC            0x00001000  /* File was synced */

 #define FS_UNMOUNT     0x00002000  /* inode on umount fs */
 #define FS_Q_OVERFLOW      0x00004000  /* Event queued overflowed */
diff --git a/include/linux/inotify.h b/include/linux/inotify.h
index d33041e..244a132 100644
--- a/include/linux/inotify.h
+++ b/include/linux/inotify.h
@@ -38,6 +38,7 @@ struct inotify_event {
 #define IN_DELETE      0x00000200  /* Subfile was deleted */
 #define IN_DELETE_SELF     0x00000400  /* Self was deleted */
 #define IN_MOVE_SELF       0x00000800  /* Self was moved */
+#define IN_SYNC            0x00001000  /* File was synced */

 /* the following are legal events.  they are sent as needed to any watch */
 #define IN_UNMOUNT     0x00002000  /* Backing fs was unmounted */
@@ -64,7 +65,7 @@ struct inotify_event {
 #define IN_ALL_EVENTS  (IN_ACCESS | IN_MODIFY | IN_ATTRIB | IN_CLOSE_WRITE | \
             IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE | IN_OPEN | IN_MOVED_FROM | \
             IN_MOVED_TO | IN_DELETE | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE_SELF | \
-            IN_MOVE_SELF)
+            IN_MOVE_SELF | IN_SYNC)

 /* Flags for sys_inotify_init1.  */
 #define IN_CLOEXEC O_CLOEXEC
diff --git a/mm/msync.c b/mm/msync.c
index 632df45..b1665ac 100644
--- a/mm/msync.c
+++ b/mm/msync.c
@@ -13,6 +13,7 @@
 #include <linux/file.h>
 #include <linux/syscalls.h>
 #include <linux/sched.h>
+#include <linux/fsnotify.h>

 /*
  * MS_SYNC syncs the entire file - including mappings.
@@ -83,6 +84,9 @@ SYSCALL_DEFINE3(msync, unsigned long, start, size_t, len, int, flags)
            get_file(file);
            up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
            error = vfs_fsync(file, 0);
+               if (!error)
+                   fsnotify_sync(file->f_path.dentry);
+
            fput(file);
            if (error || start >= end)
                goto out;
-- 
1.8.2
```

Patch has been tested on v2.6.37 of the Linux Kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You could mprotect the corresponding page in RAM (set it read-only) and catch the SIGSEGV signal when a write fails.  In the signal handler, you would need to set the RAM read-write to allow the write to succeed (this is basically reacting to page faults in user-space).  And then, you would need to re-protect the RAM to detect the next writes.

This is hard core C code which is architecture specific (not portable) but I did it in the past (in 2001 on Intel Pentium servers).  This was x86 specific so I am not sure how to do this with x86_64.  I could do some archaeology in my archives to orient you in the right direction if needed (post a comment and I will dive in my old code).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that might work like that is a debugging hardware watch point.

However you are doing something wrong if you go down that route.

In order to share memory between threads, you need to implement appropriate locking and synchronization code. In that you should be able to add notification of changes when the memory is unlocked.